# Unable to create project in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am following the steps given in "Getting started: Using IBM DataStage SaaS" and still not able to create project in IBM cloud platform (IBM Cloud Pak for Data).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your limit for creation is not surpassed. Also check your account CUH storage.
If all that does not work, click on the IBM support on the top pane and you will be redirected to the support url.